# How do I make my python code run more than once without having to restart/reopen it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code

```
dict_words=input("Enter dictionary elements :").split(" ")
word=input("Enter scrambled word").lower()

def arrange(x,y):
    if len(x)==len(y):
        if set(x)==set(y):
            return True
    return False

for i in dict_words:
    if arrange(i.lower(),word):
        print("True")
        c=1
        break
if c==0:
    print("False")
```

It works fine but it only works once. I have to reopen my program (IDLE) every time I want to use a new input.

What should my new code look like?

It needs to run continuously.

Comment: You can use _loops_ to execute arbitrary code any number of times you need

Comment: Have a look at the [`schedule`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, or tell us what OS you're on and we can point you to OS-specific solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside a loop - `for` or `while`.

If you want to run your code for a specific number of times, use a `for-loop`.

```
n = int(input('How many times you want to run this: '))

for _ in range(n):
    dict_words=input("Enter dictionary elements: ").split(" ")
    word=input("Enter scrambled word: ").lower()

    def arrange(x,y):
        if len(x)==len(y):
            if set(x)==set(y):
                return True
        return False

    c = 0
    for i in dict_words:
        if arrange(i.lower(),word):
            print("True")
            c=1
            
    if c==0:
        print("False")
```

```
How many times you want to run this: 3
Enter dictionary elements: hi ram
Enter scrambled word: mra
True
Enter dictionary elements: helo hi
Enter scrambled word: ram
False
Enter dictionary elements: one two three
Enter scrambled word: neo
True
```

Comment: My program doesn't output "False" anymore after trying this approach. For context, I'm supposed to list some words and then proceed to enter a scrambled word, if the scrambled word can form one of the words on the list, then the output is "True". If it's not, then the output should be false. For example, I list "one two three four". If i input "neo" then the output should be "True" but if I enter "eeth" then it should be "False".

Comment: You should give the inputs that doesn't change ```c```. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi! I'm still encountering a problem with this since I can't run the code anymore the moment I get "False" as an output. I get a Syntax error: Invalid syntax.

Comment: Yeah, that is what happens. Do you want to run your code indefinitely without stopping ? There must be some exit condition.

Comment: That's a bad practice. You should not be running a program forever. It will eat up your memory.

Comment: Oh for context, an online code checker needs to test my code for a few number of times. The thing is, I already receive an error by the time it tries to run my code for the 2nd input. I'm guessing since my program stops running once I receive "False" as an answer. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have to mention these things clearly in your question. I have update my answer. Please check.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the number of times the online code checker (the online code checker is a program, not a person) needs to run it should not be mentioned in the code. I'm simply saying that the code checker itself decides how many times it will test my code. The code checker stops running my program once it's satisfied all the criteria. I guess at this point it doesn't matter if my program eats up the memory as long as it works.